# Surround in Windows 7 with Soundmax

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio, surround-sound

I have a asus m2n motherboard with a Soundmax 1988 chip on it. I want to have surround sound in windows 7, but i cant get it to work.

I tried a lot of different drivers, including the latest beta for Win 7. The problem is that when I configure the speakers and i do a "Test" all speakers work. But whenever I want to play some video or mp3, only the front speakers work.

In vista there was this option called "Surround Fill" that would fix this problem, however, I cant seem to find that in windows 7. (The enhancements tab is completely gone for the speakers, other output devices do have that tab).

Anybody knows the fix?

**Edit:**

I got it now kind of working by using a trial version of SRS AudioSandbox. However, the quality is quite bad since the program tries to create a real 5.1 of stereo sound. I just want to have stereo over 4 speakers instead of fake 5.1 over 4 speakers.

Comment: Doesn't the mp3 have to contain info for all channels? It should play on all the speakers, but I don't know if you'll have more than 2 channels. Maybe I don't fully understand this concept...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem in Windows 7, there are various drivers that sort of work with minor issues.
But I eventually found the proper link with ASUS

[SoundMAX Audio Driver v6.10.x.6585 for Windows 7 32/64bit released July 31, 2009  WHQL](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/audio/SoundMAXAD1988B_Audio_V610X6585_Win7.zip)

Install that and you should have no problems like me (you will still have to tick 'Surround fill')

Comment: I got the link from here: http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20061223034227274

Comment: This helped, however, the trick was to eneable the "sonic features" since there is no soundfill option. Its not as good as in XP, but at least it sounds quite reasonable. Thnx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the speaker icon then click playback devices, you should see the speakers listed.

Double click them and then go to the tab enhancements and you should be able to see all the built ones that support your device, and you can click advanced to edit a few other settings.

If you can not find what you want here, try downloading and playing with different versions of drivers for your chip as the Windows Vista / 7 sound control panel hooks directly in to functions that the drivers provide - if you do not see a option that you previously had, it is likely that you are using the default driver and not one designed for the audio chip.

Comment: I dont see the enhancements tab at all. I tried a lot of different versions. Basically, I tried every version available for vista x64. 

Im absolutely positive it's not the default drivers, since instead of the enhancement tab i have a tab called "System Effetcs" which contains logos of SoundMAX and Analog devices (chip manufacturere). When I remove this driver and install the default windows "High Def audio driver", the Enhancement tab is available, however there is no sound fill option since it only recognized 2.0.

Comment: Can you right click on the speaker icon and go to playback devices then take a screenshot and put a link here?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it could be a problem with your codecs if Windows is able to work ok with surround sound, but your files are not. What player are you using? I recommend Shark007s codecs: http://shark007.net/

perhaps give them a try and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for what is usually called "speaker fill."  That means you want to take the 2-channel mp3 sound and expand it to fill in the full set of surround speakers.  You want to look for the options in your driver-specific software.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! and hear is my situation and fix...

Motherboard: Asus P5Q Deluxe

OS: Windows 7 32 bit

Driver installed: SoundMAX Intergrated Digital HD Audio

Driver Version: 6.10.1.6585

Speakers: 5.1 Sourround Sound (previously working on WinXP)

Problem: Open SoundMAX Control and test sound successfully plays through each speaker... BUT when listening to music/video in iTunes/media player etc sound only plays through front left and right speakers.

Fix: Open SoundMAX contol panel
Click "Listening Experience" Tab
Tick "Enable Sonic Focus" Box
Sound now plays through every speaker when in iTunes/media player.
Now you can adjust levels if needed for each speaker using the "Setup" Tab in SoundMax control also.

I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR;** This isn't a complete windows fix - but it does sound perfect though Chrome Flash and Adobe Flash/Air stuff - In the mean time I make do with a last.fm subscription and swearing at the developers of my computer.

I know this is an old post, and this may not be completely answering your question, but I've been battling with this myself recently.

Understandably the speaker fill is designed to poly-fill the problem but as an audiophile, I thought it sounded dreadful.

I never got the sound configurations to work correctly but after tracking down and installing the correct drivers and (You can now perform these tasks with Realtek HD Audio player) fiddling with the audio app, I stuck upon an interesting bug of which I hope someone can shed light upon.

full 5.1 surround sound works with HD films and anything built for high def audio. MP3 files played though any locally installed player are 2.1 channels, *however* audio playing though Flash is true, beautiful crisp 5.1 (joint stereo it seems) music.

For example; BBC iPlayer, Last.fm, youtube, quicktime etc... all crisp sound out of all 5  channels - iTunes, VLC, winamp, foobar and others are 2.1 channels.

This is most notable using Chrome and Firefox and tends to be dependant upon which application you use within Safari.

In essence - There is a small step I've missed to make this work with my current setup.

Within Realtek HD audio I have the following settings:

- **Speaker configuration:** *5.1 speaker configuration* (If you only have 2 and 4 channel, you need updated drivers)
- **Optional Speakers:** *Center, Subwoofer, Rear Pair*
- **FullRange Speakers**: *Front left and right*
- **Enable Bass Management**

By setting other options within the interface will cause the software to add crap/phasing/cancellation sounds to the audio.

### Things that fudge up the sound:

- **Setting *Surround Speakers* option**. This will add an odd low phase fuzz and make the channels modulate it seems. **You don't need this option**
- **Setting *Speaker Fill* option**. This just add a snow to the back speakers, cancelling some of the channels and trying to send the extrapolated frequencies to the rear, badly. **Just don't do it**
- **Setting *Room* environment**. This is the nearest option on the net I've seem to a successful 5.1 setup but it also applies a reverb to the sound. Badly. **Try it, then listen to your favourite song :s**
- **Using the *Main Volume* Balance**. Trying to set the balance with the software causing the same effect as the first surround speaker option. Best using windows default for this if you can. **Apps usually have this internal, else use the windows one**
- **Over using the Room Correction**: Small changes in the distance and decibels of the speakers doesn't cause a massive problem. But if you pimp a speaker with large values (e.g. 10 dB's) phasing occurs. **Try not to change the dB level on any speaker more than -/+5**

---

So if anyone can add more to this - I'll hand you an upvote. I doubt anyone will read all this, but it's in the interworld now -